# Incorrect value when saving enum

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-migrations

I'm having a little difficulty getting Entity Framework 5 Enums to map to an integer column in a migration.  Here's what the code looks like:

```
[Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
    public enum StudentStatusType
    {
        Student = 1,
        Graduate = 2
    }

    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public StudentStatusType Status { get; set; }
}
```

The migration looks like this:

```
public partial class EnumTest : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        AddColumn("UserProfile", "Status", c => c.Int(nullable: false, defaultValue:1));
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropColumn("UserProfile", "Status");
    }
}
```

However when I save changes it doesn't reflect them in the database.

```
var user = new UserProfile();
user.Status = UserProfile.StudentStatusType.Graduate;
user.FullName = "new";
user.UserName = "new";
users.UserProfiles.Add(user);
users.SaveChanges();
```

Database:

```
----------------------------------------------------
|UserId   |   UserName   |   FullName   |   Status |
----------------------------------------------------
|1        |   new        |   new        |   1      |
----------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Are you targeting .NET Framework 4 by any chance and not .NET Framework 4.5?

Comment: I'm targeting the .NET Framework 4.5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason for this is that the enum is nested in a class. Entity Framework does not discover nested types. Try moving the enum out of the class and see if it works.

**Edit**

EF6 now supports nested types (including enums) when using Code First approach.

Comment: That was it.  Thanks, I didn't know about that restriction.