# Code fist enum in Entity Framework 5 not added to database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm having a problem getting enums to map to a database using entity framework.  I set up a super basic class to test my problem:

```
public class Person
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public Genders Gender { get; set; }

    public enum Genders
    {
        Female, Male
    }
}
```

With a context of:

```
public DbSet<Person> Person { get; set; }
```

I'm using MVC 4 so to create the mapping I create a new controller with Person as the Model and my context as the context.  The MVC scaffolding creates the controller, views, and DB but **when I view the DB there's a table named Person with just one column - PersonId - but no Gender column**.

Extra Info:
Using MVC 4 targeting .Net 4.5 and using Entity Framework 5.0 (even double checked the dll version) and connecting to (LocalDb)\V11.0.

I've tried changing Genders to:

```
public enum Genders : Byte
{
    Female = 0, 
    Male = 1
}
```

I even tried moving Genders to a separate class as [one answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14112436/using-entity-framework-5-enums-and-code-first-migrations) suggested.

I found one [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh859576.aspx) that sets the class up the same way I had and works, the only difference is they were using a console application instead of MVC.

Am I missing something???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to define the enum *outside any* class. Do not embed it in a class.